# How to create a new type in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm very new to ElasticSearch. I have created new index and I was wondering how to put a new type "users" in it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to put a type, it will be automatically created when you put your first document with the [Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html). However, you usually want to [put a mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) before starting to put documents. When you put a mapping, the type is initialized as well.